# Assigning numerical rownames() to data.frame in decimal increments in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, naming

I have a data.frame that contains the data from 180 iterations of a script I ran previously. To be thorough (and to make reading the data easier), I was wondering if there's a way to name rows in a way that reflects these iterations wherein I tested my conditions at various thresholds.

At each iteration, my threshold increases by 0.1. Rather than naming my rows using,

```
rownames(data) <- c(1:180)
```

I'd like to name them from 1 - 18, also increasing by 0.1. So, 1, 1.1, 1.2, ..., 17.9, 18.0.

Can this be done? Thank you!

Comment: In the long run it would be better if you include iterations as a separate field instead of as row names.

Comment: I'm realizing you're right and will keep this in mind for future endeavours!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **seq** function:

```
 rownames(data) <- seq(from = 1, to = 18, by = 0.1)
```

Note that this will give you 181 numbers, so you might want to start at 1.1